# Возможна ли двойная связка элемента Textbox (точнее, его свойства Text) в C# xaml, чтобы введенные данные можно было использовать сразу в двух местах?

Tags: связывание-данных

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=Surf, Path=Solving.W1, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Comment: пусть элементы, которым нужно следить за тексбоксом, за ним и следят, то есть их биндинги указывают на текстбокс.

Comment: Конечно, можно. Привяжитесь к свойству VM любым количеством элементов.